# NLog variable changing its value in WebApi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, nlog

I have two methods in my WebApi-

```
[HttpPost]
    public object Method1(JObject objJobject)
    {
        var log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); 
        LogManager.Configuration.Variables["var1"] = "5";
        .
        .
    }

[HttpPost]
    public object Method2(JObject objJobject)
    {
        var log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); 
        LogManager.Configuration.Variables["var1"] = "6";
        .
        .
    }
```

var1 is variable in nlog config :-
${var:var1}

My issue is that , when I call Method1 , It should consider var1 value as 5 for entire request execution.
When I call Method2 , It should consider var1 value as 6 for entire request execution.

What happening in my case is :-

It is getting mixed for simultanous requests.

Eg. When Method1 is called , it considers var1=5 , but simultanously if user calls Method2 , It considers var1=6 var both Method1 and Method2.

What I want is , It should consider its respective value for entire execution.

Comment: Both the method are post and how can the controller differentiate which one to call ?.

Comment: Then you don't want to use variables at all. You probably want to use [MDLC (mapped diagnostics logical context) renderer](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer)

Comment: @mikez it seems you are master of nlog , I was searching this from morning, almost every nlog question has your answer and while posting my question I was praying , may mykez go through my question , and here you cameup with solution and it worked for me..!!! Thanks A Lot

Comment: @mikez Guess you can post your comment as answer, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use static global properties. In multithreaded envinronment you will get collisions.

Use EventProperties: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer

MDLC also can be used but it is some sort of global ambient context. EventProperties stores in LogEvent and can be used in layout or filter logic.